# Angular (and lodash) check if any items except current index have value = true

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash

I'm trying to set conditional "filters" on my data to control a user experience. What I am trying to do is have an ng-if inside a repeat that passes an index and if anything else inside its object **besides it's own index** has a value of onlyMe, return false, else return true.

So, I have my repeat and ng-if like so

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="item in marketItemsTest2">
                                    <div class="col-xs-12" ng-if="aloneNow($index)" >
```

so it passes to the alone now function which should pass true or false. I have a click else where that will toggle onlyMe to true or false on each item in the array. It's sort of an off way of filtering but I think it's the simplest way of conditionally filtering the way I want it to.

The desired effect is it will remian true unless an item that is not itself has onlyMe = true. I figured passing the index would be the best way to track it. I believe something like this is possible with lodash, I just have no idea how. The simplest way I can put it is - I want to look through the object and if any items have onlyMe = true that aren't the current index I passed, return false, else true. Is this possible?

maybe a filter by onlyMe = true exclduing the index passed? Here's my attempt at that.

```
$scope.aloneNow = function(index){
        //if no other 
        var here = _.findIndex($scope.marketItemsTest2, 'onlyMe');
        if(here == -1){
            return true;
        }else if(here == index){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }

    };
```

Would appreciate any pointers, using these libraries is new to me.  Thanks!

Comment: Is the `onlyMe` property in your model?

Comment: @ExceptionLimeCat yes exactly

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like this. You can keep track of a particular index, or ID, or collection item reference then use `ng-if` or `ng-hide`/`ng-show` to toggle items in your list. [Here's a working demo](http://jsbin.com/kilajiyido/1/edit?html,js,output).

Controller:

```
app.controller('DemoCtrl', function() {
  this.items = [
    {label: 'mustachio'},
    {label: 'top hat'},
    {label: 'monacle'},
    {label: 'smart phone'},
    {label: 'watch'},
    {label: 'cane'}
  ];

  this.isolatedIndex = false;
});
```

View:

```
<ul ng-controller="DemoCtrl as demo">
  <li ng-repeat="item in demo.items"
      ng-if="demo.isolatedIndex === false || $index === demo.isolatedIndex">
    <span>{{item.label}}</span>
    <a ng-show="demo.isolatedIndex === false"
       ng-click="demo.isolatedIndex = $index">
      only me
    </a>
    <a ng-hide="demo.isolatedIndex === false"
       ng-click="demo.isolatedIndex = false">
      all
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If this idea of a list with "onlyMe" built in is something you're doing often you'll probably want to think about wrapping the functionality up in a directive.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your issue correctly and your model has this property in it, then just use it has the flag.

**View**

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="item in marketItemsTest2">
   <div class="col-xs-12" ng-show="item.onlyMe" >
   </div>
   <a ng-click="setOnlyMe(item)">OnlyMe</a>
 </div>
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
     $scope.setOnlyMe = function (item){
            item.onlyMe = !item.onlyMe;
     };
}]);
```

This is assuming `onlyMe` is bool and can be edited.